# Linked list: remove all nodes whose next element has a larger value

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I'd like to remove in a linked list all the nodes that have a greater value to their right.

- Input: `10 -> 12 -> 15 -> 20 -> 5 -> 16 -> 25 -> 8 -> NULL`
- Expected output:  `20 -> 25 -> 8 -> NULL`
- Actual Output: `20 -> 25 ->`

Kindly help me resolve the bug.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *ptr;
}*start=NULL, *t, *last=NULL;

int i=0;

int main() {
    //creation
    int size;
    printf("Enter size:");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    while (size--) {
        t = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter list:");
        scanf("%d", &(t->data));
        t->ptr = NULL;
        if (start == NULL) {
            start = t;
        } else
            last->ptr = t;
        last = t;
    }

    //display
    printf("\n");
    t = start;
    do {
        printf("%d->", t->data);
        t = t->ptr;
    } while (t != NULL);
    printf("NULL\n");

    //main objective
    struct node *t1,*t2;
    t1=start;
    t2=t1->ptr;
    t=start;
    for(t=start;t!=NULL;t=t->ptr){
        if(t1->data>t2->data||t->ptr==NULL){
            printf("%d->", t->data);
        }
        t1=t1->ptr;
        t2=t2->ptr;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the segmentation fault due to illegal memory access by verifying that `t2` is not null before attempting to dereference the pointer. This version runs clean after adding guards to `t2`:

```
for (t = start; t; t = t->ptr) {
    if (!t2 || (t1 && t1->data > t2->data)) {
        printf("%d->", t->data);
    }

    t1 = t1->ptr;

    if (t2) {
        t2 = t2->ptr;
    }
}
```

Although this shows the correct output, the list isn't actually modified, so we're simply producing a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), rendering the routine useless for manipulating the data in memory for other purposes.

A few additional suggestions:

- There's no need for global variables in this program.
- Avoid unnecessary variables (`t` and `t1` are basically the same, so it's easy to remove one of these. We can also remove `t2` and use `t->ptr` instead).
- Give variables descriptive names.
- Use spacing around operators.
- Separate logical chunks of code into separate functions rather than adding comments in `main` to delimit them.
- Free allocated memory when finished with it.
- No need to [cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Here's a version that modifies the list in-place and implements the above points:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *ptr;
};

void remove_right_larger(struct node **head) {    
    for (struct node *curr = *head, *prev = NULL;
         curr; curr = curr->ptr) {
        if (curr->ptr && curr->data < curr->ptr->data) {
            if (prev) {
                prev->ptr = curr->ptr;
            }
            else {
                *head = curr->ptr;
            }

            free(curr);
        }
        else {
            prev = curr; 
        }
    }
}

void print_list(struct node *head) {
    for (; head; head = head->ptr) {
        printf("%d->", head->data);
    }

    puts("NULL");
}

void free_list(struct node *head) {
    while (head) {
        struct node *tmp = head;
        head = head->ptr;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

struct node *input_list() {
    struct node *start = NULL;
    struct node *last = NULL;
    int size;
    printf("Enter size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    while (size--) {
        struct node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
        tmp->ptr = NULL;
        printf("Enter list: ");
        scanf("%d", &(tmp->data));

        if (start) {
            last->ptr = tmp;
        } 
        else {
            start = tmp;
        }

        last = tmp;
    }

    return start;
}

int main() {
    struct node *head = input_list();
    print_list(head);
    remove_right_larger(&head);
    print_list(head);
    free_list(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing `Core Dump/Segmentation fault` which is a specific kind of error caused by accessing memory that “does not belong to you.”

The iteration before the last one, you're setting `t1 <- 8` & `t2 <- NULL`. So when you enter the last iteration, you check `t1->data` with `t2->data` with in `if()`, which resutls in accessing `NULL->data` (you're not allowed).

To fix this, you need to add some extra condition to handle this case.